# Latency in sending bulk sms using QSerialPort

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

My Qt application uses GSM Modem to send notifications.(Web based solution isn't an option). The application take about 3 seconds to send the SMS to 100 phone numbers. Should I be worried that some of them may not be sent because of the slow nature of COM Commands? The modem used is a ZTE 21 mbps HSPDA Modem. Does `QSerialPort` wait until an SMS Has been sent to send another?

Comment: Due to serial nature of communication, I believe this latency is quite expected. You need not be worried. And, you are right in your deduction of sequential sending of messages through serial port. In addition, you should conduct some more tests to build an understanding of the latency involved e.g. 10, 50, 100, 150, 200, etc. messages.

Comment: Take the BaudRate that you're setting on the port and calculate how many bytes per second fits in that port.